# Failing to load token.pickle of google api calendar in python when deployed on to docker container

Tags: python, docker, google-api-client, google-api-python-client, docker-container

I'm trying to make a call to the google calendar api and retrieve the holiday events. I am using  an api call to google calendar, works fine on my local, but when i host it on docker container its not working.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import pickle
    import os.path
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
    
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']
    
    def main():
       """
       Shows basic usage of the People API.
        Prints the name of the first 10 connections.
        """
        creds = None
        # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
        service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

I am able to load in the line "creds = pickle.load(token)" on my local but not on the container. Do we need to do any settings on the container in order to access google api from the container or is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: "I am able to load in the line" - what does that mean?  Are you getting an error message?  If so, please add it to your question.  Tell us what exactly is the bad behavior.

Comment: You ask about accessing the Google API, but all your program is trying to do is read a file from local disk.  The problem must be that you haven't made the `token.pickle` file available in the container, at the right location, with the right permissions, so that your program finds it and reads it.  That's really the only reason that that particular line of code can fail.

Answer (score -1):

`flow.run_local_server()` is bound to localhost inside the container.

Start docker using `--net=host` (or `docker-compose use network_mode:"host"`).

see full answer at https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/issues/87#issuecomment-685094486